# wish to ingore .htaccess restrictions during ajax page include

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I am not .htaccess expert, however over time I've built one from various posts that works.

This section

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Causes all pages go through index.php.  That works fine.  However, it is forcing at least one of my ajax pages to go through index.php which is not desirable.  Does anyone know how I can limit this .htaccess code to only effect during the initial site visit and not ajax loads ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make the AJAX request to a regular file (with size)? This way, the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s` condition will fail and the rewrite rule will not be used.

Otherwise, you could try this to skip the rewrite if the request has the common (but not standard) `X-Requested-With` HTTP header

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'll break it down for you below...

Most JS libraries or browsers (can't remember exactly), when sending an AJAX request, will inject an HTTP header `X-Requested-With` with value `XMLHttpRequest`. You can use HTTP headers in a `RewriteCond` like `%{HTTP:X-Requested-With} =XMLHttpRequest` to detect an AJAX request. Using `!=` means the request is not via AJAX.

Comment: I really did not understand how this return code of you worked. For instance you use the string 'ajax' but I am not sure why. Could you be specific there ?  

Thanks.

Comment: Your code almost worked for me! But in some cases (calling from Ionic app) it didn't work. I managed to do it with the rule written like this: RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-requested-with} =^XMLHttpRequest$